# Iterate through multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering how can I get the multidimensional array like [[A1, B1, C1....],[A2, B2, C2....]];

```js
let grid = [
  []
];
let letters = "abcdefghij".toUpperCase();

// create the Grid
const createGrid = (size) => {
  let row = 0;
  let col = 0;
  for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    grid[row] = [];
    for (col = 0; col < letters.length; col++) {
      grid[row][col] = `${letters[row]}${col + 1}`;
    }
  }
};

createGrid(letters.length);
console.log(grid);
```

Comment: You can just swap the `row` and `col` in your cell assignment like `${letters[col]}${row + 1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer the `col` instead of the `row` and concat the `row + 1` to it in the inner loop when you are doing the assignment.

```js
let grid = [
  []
];
let letters = "abcdefghij".toUpperCase();

// create the Grid
const createGrid = (size) => {
  let row = 0;
  let col = 0;
  for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    grid[row] = [];
    for (col = 0; col < letters.length; col++) {
      // instead of grid[row][col] = `${letters[row]}${col + 1}`;
      grid[row][col] = `${letters[col]}${row + 1}`;
    }
  }
};

createGrid(letters.length);
console.log(grid);
```

Comment: Thanks, Ran, but what about if I want to keep both results, like 2 different multidimensional arrays, one will be the cols and one will be the rows.

Comment: To be more specific; the first grid will be [['A1', 'A2'...], ['B1', 'B2'...]] and the second one will be [['A1', 'B1'...], ['A2', 'B2'...]]

Comment: In this case you can have two grid variables. in the same iteration you can assign them both (one like you did and the second one like I showed you)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind converting your code to ES6+, this one should do the trick.

```js
const letters = "abcdefghij".toUpperCase();

const createGrid = (letters) => Array.from(
    { length: letters.length },
    (_, index) => [...letters].map((letter) => `${letter}${index + 1}`)
);

console.log(createGrid(letters));
```